# Visual Studio Option to fill in standard menu items?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, menu

When designing a WinForms app in visual studio, you can choose to populate a menu bar with the standard set of File, Save, Help, About, etc. Is there a way to do this in WPF using visual studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you must add the menu items youself in wpf, but it is very easy to do, here is an example:

```
<Menu IsMainMenu="True">
  <MenuItem Header="_File" />
  <MenuItem Header="_Edit">
    <MenuItem Header="_Cut"/>
    <MenuItem Header="_Copy"/>
    <MenuItem Header="_Paste"/>
  </MenuItem>
  <MenuItem Header="_View" />
  <MenuItem Header="_Window" />
  <MenuItem Header="_Help" />
</Menu>
```

for more detail see - http://www.wpftutorial.net/Menus.html

Comment: The link doesn't mention how to hook up commands and keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: however: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10209231/bind-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-a-command-in-the-view-model-in-wpf

Comment: @EamonnMcEvoy in WinForms the command :Insert Standart Menu Item..." populate items with the key-shorcut and the icons.