# Bind a keyboard shortcut to a command in the view model in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have an application where I have a `UserControl` with a toolbar in it. This toolbar has a button `Execute` which in turn has its command bound to an `ICommand` derived class that the viewmodel exposes as a property.

```
<Button Grid.Row="0" Command="{Binding ExecuteCommand}">Execute</Button>
```

Now, I'd like to bind this to a keyboard shortcut (`F5`) as well. This needs to be bound in the context of the `UserControl` since, it's only applicable if this usercontrol is visible at the moment.

Another option is to bind it to the `KeyDown` of the textbox that actually contains the text to execute, but I'm really shaky when it comes to how to route the event from the control to the command in the viewmodel without really ugly hacks in the code-behind of the usercontrol.

Any pointers are appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Keyboard shortcuts in WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361350/keyboard-shortcuts-in-wpf)

Comment: It's along the same lines, but it's not really the same question. That talks about how to bind standard commands, while this binds a custom command to a property in the view models. The solution turned out to be similar but still, different things.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: yeah I don't think its a duplicate, or at least the solution provided in the other question is poor (it's the WinForms solution to a MVVM problem).

Comment: @sixlettervariables: I don't see any winforms in the question or answer

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: I meant WinForms as an adjective to meaning *low quality* or *not helpful* for WPF/MVVM.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There was another answer that disappeared for some reason. This worked fine:

```
<UserControl.InputBindings>
  <KeyBinding Key="F5" Command="{Binding ExecuteCommand}" />
</UserControl.InputBindings>
```

I'd like to give credit to that guy if possible. Please appear again :)

Answer (score 2):

Afaik, there isn't a way to directly bind to a keypress, but there are some work arounds. It looks like others have had this problem as well, have you seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711038/key-press-inside-of-textbox-mvvm)? My other suggestion is to look into [attached commands](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/12/13/attachedcommandbehavior-v2-aka-acb/).