# Shortcut hotkey for WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I used UserControl for my application and i need to put shortcut key for my application i placed this code but not working.Anyone suggestion plz

My XAML Code

```
<Button  Name="ucBtnUpload" ToolTip="Upload F2" Cursor="Hand" Click="ucBtnUpload_Click" KeyUp="ucBtnUpload_KeyUp_1" >
```

My Code Behind

```
private void ucBtnUpload_KeyUp_1(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
if (e.Key == Key.F2)
            {

                Test opj = new Test();
                opj.ShowDialog();

             }
}
```

Comment: Does your handler get fired? Have you wired up the event in the XAML, correctly? `<ucBtnUpload ... OnClick="ucBtnUpload_KeyUp_1"...>`

Comment: <Button  Name="ucBtnUpload" ToolTip="Upload F2" Cursor="Hand" Click="ucBtnUpload_Click" KeyUp="ucBtnUpload_KeyUp_1" >

Comment: Are you sure that you want a Key-Event on a button? This requires that the button is Focused...

Comment: Usually you do this via InputBindings and commands in WPF, not by intercepting key events and handling them.

Comment: Yes works fine mine too when i use sample application but i use it to my project nothing will happen. Thats why i mention i use it User control for my application

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keyboard shortcuts in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361350/keyboard-shortcuts-in-wpf)

Answer (score 5):

You need to try something similar to this

```
private void AddHotKeys()
{
        try
        {
            RoutedCommand firstSettings = new RoutedCommand();
            firstSettings.InputGestures.Add(new KeyGesture(Key.A, ModifierKeys.Alt));
            CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(firstSettings , My_first_event_handler));

            RoutedCommand secondSettings = new RoutedCommand();
            secondSettings.InputGestures.Add(new KeyGesture(Key.B, ModifierKeys.Alt));
            CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(secondSettings , My_second_event_handler));
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            //handle exception error
        }
}
```

Events

```
private void My_first_event_handler(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e) 
{
      //handler code goes here.
      MessageBox.Show("Alt+A key pressed");
}

private void My_second_event_handler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{
     //handler code goes here. 
     MessageBox.Show("Alt+B key pressed");
}
```

> If you are following MVVM you could try this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10209231/bind-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-a-command-in-the-view-model-in-wpf)

```
<UserControl.InputBindings>
<KeyBinding Modifiers="Control" 
            Key="E" 
            Command="{input:CommandBinding EditCommand}"/>
```

[See the reference](http://codesamplez.com/development/wpf-hotkeys-c-sharp) 
[msdn adding key bindings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keybinding(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this in your xaml

```
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding MyCommand}" Key="F2"/>
</Window.InputBindings>

<Button Command="{Binding MyCommand}"/>
```

MyCommand is an ICommand implemented in your windows' / view's viewmodel.

So both the button and the F2 inputbinding will execute the same command.